# selectbox with options which is populated from mysql gets a whitespace/newline

Tags: php, mysql

I populate a selectbox from a mysql database:

```
      <?php
//Query the database for the results we want
                            $queryBesteller = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM bestellers");

//Create an array of objects for each returned row
                            while ($bestellerArray[] = $queryBesteller->fetch_object());

//Remove the blank entry at end of array
                            array_pop($bestellerArray);
                            ?>

   <label for="customerNameLabel">Naam Besteller</label>
                                <select name="bestellers" id="bestellerSelectBox" >
                                    <option>Selecteer Besteller</option>
                                    <?php foreach ($bestellerArray as $option) : ?>

                                        <option  value="<?php echo $option->name; ?>"><?php echo $option->name; ?></option>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
```

Most of the names are populated like this:

```
<option value="Harry Parry">Harry Parry</option>
```

But some also get this, and this is fault:

```
<option value="Hans Petersonasd
">Hans Petersonasd
</option>
```

Because i later want to get other data from mysql on basis of the name, but if there is a space then it won't work.

I tried to use trim in Sql but also didnt fix

**Answer:**
I tried trimming like the answers below but that also didn't fix.
I deleted the rows from the table and re-added them and then it worked

Comment: Updated my answer, please try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I tried trimming like the answers below but that also didn't fix. I deleted the rows from the table and re-added them and then it worked

Comment: Please run the query in my answer and let us know, if your php/html is exactly as show the issue can only lie in your data.

Comment: i runned the query and it seems there is no trailing spaces or so but still got the /n

Comment: Updated my answer, try again

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
<?php foreach ($bestellerArray as $option) : ?>

    <option  value="<?php echo trim($option->name); ?>"><?php echo trim($option->name); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would fix the issue with your data at source by executing this MySQL query:

```
UPDATE bestellers SET name = REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM col_name), 
                                     TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM col_name), 
                                     TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM col_name),
                                     TRIM(TRAILING '\r\n' FROM col_name));
```

This will serve to trim newlines and whitespace from the name field in all rows of this `bestellers` table. The reason that just using `TRIM(name)` didn't work for you was that newlines are your issue and `TRIM()` alone only removes whitespaces.